# How to keep an never ending process in an async thread

Tags: swift, macos

I have built a command line app that will listen for an argument and kick off a never-ending process. What I can't seem to figure out is how to keep that process running until I send a different argument back to the command line app to end it. I am able to accomplish this easily in the main thread, but I want to be able to gain access to the command prompt to issue an end command to stop that process.

My first thought was to go to threading, but I can't seem to get that to work. What is the solution you would use in this case?

Comment: try to run in asynchronously: `DispatchQueue.main.async {never ending process}` or create your own `queue`

Comment: There's no such thing as as "async thread". There's only "thread"